# Cargar DataTable con Jquery

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, datatables

Estoy intentando cargar un DataTable dinamicamente, he intentado seguir unos cuantos tutoriales y adaptarlo a lo que tengo pero no me funciona, espero puedan ayudarme.

En una vista pido un rango de fechas y un almacen que se escoge de un select, esto lo envio al controlador y me regresa un response con la consulta, hasta aqui todo lo tengo bien.

**Controlador:**

```
public function consultaProd2(Request $request)
{
    $almacenes = Almacen::lists('nombre', 'id');

    $fechas = explode(' ', $request['RangoFecha']);
    $fechaInicial = $fechas[0].' 00:00:00';
    $fechaFinal = $fechas[2].' 23:59:59';

    $productos = Producto::whereBetween('created_at', [$fechaInicial, $fechaFinal])
                         ->where('almacen_id', '=', $request['Almacen'])
                         ->get();

    return response()->json($productos);


}
```

Mi problema viene siendo en el JQuery, aquí tengo lo siguiente:

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function llenar(response, index, value)
    {
        $('#example1').DataTable({
            "destroy": true,
            "columns":[
                {"data":"response.nombre"},
                {"data":"response.codigo"},
                {"data":"response.codigo"},
                {"data":"response.codigo"},
                {"data":"response.codigo"},
                {"data":"response.codigo"},
                {"data":"response.codigo"},
                {"data":"response.codigo"},
                {"data":"response.codigo"},
                {"data":"response.codigo"},
                {"data":"response.codigo"}
            ]
        });
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function consultaProducto(){
        var tablaDatos = $('#datos');
        var token = $("#token").val();
        var route = '<?= url('producto/consultaProducto') ?>'
        var data = {};
        data.Almacen = $('select[name=Almacen]').val();
        data.RangoFecha = $('input[name=RangoFecha]').val();
        if(data.Almacen != null || data.Almacen !== 'undefined'){
            if(data.RangoFecha != null || data.RangoFecha !== 'undefined'){
                $.ajax({
                    url: route,
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
                    data: data,
                    method: 'POST',
                    statusCode: {
                        400: function() {
                            /*success: function(){

                            }*/
                        }
                    }
                }).done(function(response){
                    $.each(response, function(index, value){
                        llenar(response, index, value);
                        /*tablaDatos.append("<tr>");
                        tablaDatos.append("<td>"+response[index].nombre+"</td>");
                        tablaDatos.append("<td>"+response[index].codigo+"</td>");
                        tablaDatos.append("</tr>");*/
                    });

                }).fail(function(response){
                }); 
            }else{
                alert("Debes seleccionar un rango de fecha");
            }
        }else{
            alert("Debes seleccionar un almacen");
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Si imprimo dentro de `done` con `console.log(response)`, me trae el JSON de la manera correcta.

[image: a busy cat]

Especificamente la función de llenar es la que no estoy seguro que este funcionando y no me marca error alguno al momento de cargar la vista e interactuar con ella. Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Deberías estar seguro de si la funcion `llenar` hace lo que tiene que hacer.. has hecho algún tipo de log para el llenado?  Un saludo

Comment: Coincido con lo comentado por lois6b; agrego que revises tu funcion donde llenas la tabla (claro una vez que tengas cierto esta correcto su uso) que en el $.each(response...) {...} sea llamada como "llenar(this);" modifiques la funcion para que solo reciba un parámetro y (asumiendo dejas como nombre al parámetro "response") tomes cada dato como response.nombre, response.presentacion... (asi como se mira en la imagen del JSON que recibes. Como ahora lo tienes, pasas la respuesta el "response" pasas index y value pero no usas más que el "response" en función "llnear".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia tu función llenar de esta forma:

```
function llenar(response, index, value)
{
    $('#example1').DataTable({
        "destroy": true,
        "data": response,
        "columns":[
            {"data":"nombre"},
            {"data":"codigo"},
            {"data":"codigo"},
            {"data":"codigo"},
            {"data":"codigo"},
            {"data":"codigo"},
            {"data":"codigo"},
            {"data":"codigo"},
            {"data":"codigo"},
            {"data":"codigo"},
            {"data":"codigo"}
        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me has salvado